# Xamarin mouse_event(Touch) process

Tags: xamarin, service, xamarin.android, mouseevent

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern void mouse_event(Enum.MouseEventFlags dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);
--This is a Windows API
```

Hi.
I have a problem about xamarin.android.

I have a service. And i want to do touch process with service.
"Click,dragdrop,right click".

How can i do this with Xamarin.

Comment: wait how do you right click on a mobile device?

Comment: long time to left click press

Comment: Can you at least show an eg of what you want may be with images?

Comment: Please look at the link photo. [Image Link](https://ibb.co/nfYH0x) I want to do it like TeamViewer Android Application.

Comment: Hi, Xamarin.forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: For Xamarin.Android

Comment: Do you have any idea.